# How can I detect twitter limit exceeded in json response

Tags: java, android, json, twitter, twitter4j

I am parsing the result from

```
    http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="+"from:" 
                        + searchTerm + "&rpp="+limit;
```

Not sure what to look/how to parse for rate limit exceeded? Whats a reliable way to check this before looking for tweets in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is a rate limit of 350 requests per hour when using OAuth. I believe it's 150 when using Basic Auth which will be deprecated in June.

I think the best way to achieve that is by counting your own requests per hour to avoid breaking this limit

Comment: Ok. but what does the format of the json look like when it informs of the rate limit?